# Apache vhosts 2 domains

Tags: apache-2.2, lamp, virtualhost

com and .co.uk domains, is it possible to create a virtual host to point to a single directory on the box?

At present I have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.co.uk
    ServerAlias domain.co.uk
    DocumentRoot "C:/htdocs/domain.com/htdocs"

    <Directory />
    Options +Includes
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog  "C:/htdocs/domain.co.uk/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/htdocs/domain.co.uk/logs/access.log" combined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes just add them to your ServerAlias

```
ServerAlias domain.co.uk www.domain.com domain.com
```

Or you could do it like this:

```
ServerName domain.co.uk
ServerAlias *.domain.co.uk domain.com *.domain.com
```

I think you have som inconsistency problems with your posted code. Using both `C:/htdocs/domain.co.uk/` and `C:/htdocs/domain.com/`

If it was up to me. I would put everything in `C:/htdocs/domain.com/` and use the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com domain.co.uk *.domain.co.uk
    DocumentRoot "C:/htdocs/domain.com/htdocs"

    <Directory />
        Options +Includes
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog  "C:/htdocs/domain.com/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/htdocs/domain.com/logs/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Please note, when using `*.domain.com` (star-alias) in ServerAlias. If you wish to add a specific subdomain (example delicious-subs.domain.co.uk) in a new VirtualHost - pointing to another location. Then you will have to add that new VirtualHost with above/before the VirtualHost using the star-alias.

Comment: Great, worked a treat thanks for the help and the tip

Comment: You're most welcome ;)